# Grass 6 extension installation in Grass 7 error

Tags: grass-gis, error, installation

I am trying to install the extension r.roughness from the Grass 6 repository, but in Grass 7.

When trying g.extensions, the error "make: *** No rule to make target `/home/peter_s/grass_data/CLB/CLB_June_2013/.tmp/Peter/8657.0/r.roughness/scripts/r.roughness.window.vector', needed by`script'.  Stop.".

When getting the extension from svn and compiling in the folder with $ make MODULE_TOPDIR=/usr/local/grass-7.0.svn/ I get a similar error: 
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/local/grass-7.0.svn/scripts/r.roughness.window.vector', needed by`script'.  Stop.

Any ideas where the bug is?

Thanks in advance!!
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are addons for GRASS 6.x ([addons](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/AddOns/GRASS_6)) and there are others for GRASS 7 ([addons](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/AddOns/GRASS_7))

Since the future version 7 (still being developed with several versions per month, which do you use ?) marks a major break with the 6.x versions (new vector API, etc.) it is doubtful that all GRASS 6.x addons works without problems (there is no r.roughness in [GRASS 7 raster addons](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/AddOns/GRASS7/raster))

So, if you want to use r.roughness without bugs or problems, use the 6.4.x version (I have no problem with the official stable version (6.4.2) and with the future version (6.4.3RC3)

Comment: Thanks, gene!
I will try it with GRASS 6, then.

All the best, 
Peter

Comment: OK, it seems to work in Grass 6. 
Note for others: command for command line is r.roughness.window.vector

Comment: One more problem: Only the command r.roughness.vector works - but for my task the calculation between surface and area of square cells would be more suited, which is what "r.roughness.window.area" does. That command does not work, however ([Errno 2] No such file or directory). 
Ideas why that is?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: needed to copy the r.roughness.window.area script from the src folder into /usr/local/grass-6.4.3svn/scripts
r.roughness.window.vector was there, but r.roughness.window.area was not.