# Cannot run Grass algorithms in QGIS 2.18 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, ubuntu, qgis-processing

I have QGIS and GRASS installed through the UbuntuGIS repositories. If I try to execute any GRASS 6 or 7 algorithm I get the following error message:

`"This algorithm cannot be run :-( It seems that GRASS GIS 7 is not correctly installed and configured in your system. Please install it before running GRASS GIS 7 algorithms."`

I checked other questions on this issue however most deal with Setup on Windows systems:

- ["Missing dependency.This algorithm cannot be run :-(" QGIS + GRASS Windows 7](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103565/missing-dependency-this-algorithm-cannot-be-run-qgis-grass-windows-7)
- [Grass 6 extension installation in Grass 7 error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62783/grass-6-extension-installation-in-grass-7-error)
- [How to make GRASS 7 addon available in QGIS 2.12?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172263/how-to-make-grass-7-addon-available-in-qgis-2-12)

On linux I do not have to configure the path of the GRASS folder as the [QGIS help](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html) on configuring external applications tells me. Grass runs from the shell by typing `grass`. The Grass-version called by the shell is `GRASS 7.2.0 (2016)`.

Furthermore i checked that GRASS 6 and 7 is activated in the additional providers menu in the toolbox of QGIS.

Any suggestion what could be done to fix this?

**Edit**

Meanwhile I completly uninstalled and reinstalled `qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass` from the oficial QGIS repositories...but the error continues.

**Edit 2**
Checking out the logs for qgis in the Log Messages Panel I found out under the "plugins" tab that the grass plugin does not load properly:

```
2017-01-23T14:10:22 1   Failed to load /usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassplugin7.so (Reason: Cannot load library /usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassplugin7.so: (libgrass_gis.7.0.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))
2017-01-23T14:10:22 1   Failed to load /usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassprovider7.so (Reason: Cannot load library /usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassprovider7.so: (libgrass_gis.7.0.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))
2017-01-23T14:10:22 1   Failed to load /usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassrasterprovider7.so (Reason: Cannot load library /usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassrasterprovider7.so: (libgrass_gis.7.0.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))
```

Comment: For Edit2: It seems that GRASS 7.0.3 is searched for, but you only have 7.2.0 on disk. Don't mix Ubuntugis and non-ubuntugis packages.

Comment: @AndreJ I think this mixup is probably the main problem. I might have added ubuntugis and qgis repositories. I tried to add only the qgis repositories and reinstall all. but it did not fix this yet. now i do not get any message that the plugin is loaded although it is installed. any suggestion on how I could clean up any remaining mess?

Comment: Either downgrade GRASS to 7.0.3, or remove the QGIS debian packages (with purge, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application  ), return to ubuntgis and follow the workaround in my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I get the same error with the Ubuntugis version of QGIS and GRASS version 7.2.0.

It seems that 7.2 is not yet correctly adopted in processing. There is already a ticket for it: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/16019 and https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2017-January/046671.html

As a workaround, you may edit (as sudo) `/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/Grass7Utils.py` line 251 to

```
            command = 'grass72 ' + Grass7Utils.grassMapsetFolder() \
```

and line 103 of `Grass7AlgorithmProvider.py` to

```
    return 'grass72'
```

Or downgrade to GRASS 7.0.3 from the main Ubuntu repo.

GRASS 6 commands will not work with GRASS 7, so you can deactivate the 161 `GRASS` commands.

---

Just another workaround from the mailing list https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2017-January/038907.html

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/grass72 /usr/bin/grass70`

---

**UPDATE**

Also reported with http://hub.qgis.org/issues/16110 and fixed with http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/repository/revisions/099e7a77f2c32f469539f542a31df7b0d4b77dd3 That should work for GRASS versions 7.0 up to 7.3

Unfortunately, the fix has not been applied to QGIS 2.18.4, so the workarounds are still necessary.

Comment: okay. the workaround did not work for me. i tried but it failed. However downgrading through synaptics package manager to grass 7.0 did the trick. how can I assure that with the next software update it does not upgrade to 7.2. again? I already removed qgis and ubuntugis repositories from the sources list however it seems that the oficial ubuntu repositories already contain grass 7.2...at least if i open the software center it offers me 7.2.

Comment: From http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=grass&searchon=names I see GRASS 7.2 only for zesty. Maybe the software center still has the ubuntugis entry listed. Try `apt-cache policy grass` in a Terminal window to see what is really available.

Comment: the symlink did not work for me.. I am on Mint with qgis compiled from source and run from the output folder. Do I have also other configurations to edit? Thanks!

Comment: QGIS and ubuntugis unfortunately are often out of sync. So this time when I saw that there was an upgrade of GRASS, I did not install it. Just wonder how to find out when the right time has come. The official channels seem to ignore this really annoying problem most of the time. It's not fun having a broken QGIS every three months or so.

Comment: @BerndV. I usually install new Linux versions first in a virtual box for testing.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the problem by reinstalling grass 7.0.3 from the qgis repository.
The grass from Ubuntugis repo is version 7.2, which is not support by QGIS.

1. remove the GRASS GIS by
   sudo apt-get remove grass grass-core grass-doc grass-gui
2. disable ubuntugis-unstable repository
3. sudo apt-get install grass grass-gui

It works for me.