# Linux QGIS 2.18.4 GRASS7 tools not working

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, linux, qgis-grass-plugin

GRASS tools are showing & GRASS 7 shows as activated in the Providers menu, but I get the "Missing dependency, GRASS isn't configured properly" message. How do I configure it properly?

GRASS 7.2 standalone shows in the main menu but doesn't run - a window flashes up momentarily.

This is a recent install of 2.18 after removing 2.16.
I did this to install:

`add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable 
then 
apt-get update # apt-get install qgis apt-get update # apt-get install qgis apt-get update # apt-get install qgis 
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass`

I've read threads on here but [Cannot run Grass algorithms in QGIS 2.18 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225464/cannot-run-grass-algorithms-in-qgis-2-18-on-ubuntu-16-04) may be close although I haven't mixed sources - how do I find what version of GRASS - both standalone & plugins is (partially?) installed?

In a previous post, AndreJ stated:

> You ran into gdal-abi-2-1-2 but it is not installable because that is only available for xenial. Trusty is still at gdal-abi-2-1-0. You might need to upgrade GDAL before installing QGIS.

I've overcome the xenial problem (ie using trusty), is the gdal version still a problem?  How do I find out?

FWIW, SAGA is installed and working.