# Get Grass to work in Processing using QGIS 2.18.16 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, ubuntu

Executing a GRASS command in QGIS 2.18.16 via Processing returns the error:

*This algorithm cannot be run :-( 
It seems that GRASS is not correctly installed and configured in your system. Please install it before running GRASS algorithms.*

The solutions provided at [Cannot run Grass algorithms in QGIS 2.18 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225464) do not work for the following reasons.

1. As a workaround, you may edit (as sudo) /usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/Grass7Utils.py line 251 to

   ```
       command = 'grass72 ' + Grass7Utils.grassMapsetFolder() \
   ```

I do not believe that line 251 is the correct location for this code.  This area of code is between line 242 and 264.

```
    @staticmethod
    def writeGrass7Window(filename):
      out = open(filename, 'w')
      out.write('proj:       0\n')
      out.write('zone:       0\n')
      out.write('north:      1\n')
      out.write('south:      0\n')
      out.write('east:       1\n')
      out.write('west:       0\n')
      out.write('cols:       1\n')
      out.write('rows:       1\n')
      out.write('e-w resol:  1\n')
      out.write('n-s resol:  1\n')
      out.write('top:        1\n')
      out.write('bottom:     0\n')
      out.write('cols3:      1\n')
      out.write('rows3:      1\n')
      out.write('depths:     1\n')
      out.write('e-w resol3: 1\n')
      out.write('n-s resol3: 1\n')
      out.write('t-b resol:  1\n')
    out.close()
```

2. I tried the second solution to add a soft link but that returned an error.

   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/grass72/usr/bin/grass70
   ln: failed to create symbolic link './grass70': File exists
3. I uninstalled GRASS, disconnected from the unstable ubuntu qgis repository and reinstalled GRASS but it reinstalls 7.2.  There is no version 7.0 available at GRASS for download.

   How do I get GRASS to work within Processing using Ubuntu QGIS 2.18.16?

Comment: Keep in mind that the linked question is over a year old, the python scripts may have changed since then. Looking at ubuntugis unstable, I see they have Grass 7.4.0 by now, but QGIS is not yet ready for that. What OS version are you running?

Comment: @AndreJ.  I am running Ubuntu 16.04.  I have updated/edited my question.  Thanks.

Comment: The main ubuntu repo has GRASS 7.0.3. Make sure to remove and purge your QGIS and GRASS 7.2, then remove the ubuntugis ppa from your sources, switch to qgis.org/debian trusty and run `apt-cache policy grass` to see what is available for you.